# C#/UNITY How do I make a button change the screen resolution?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was wondering how I could make my button change the screen resolution. I have this so far, but I do not really know how to make it work with the button. Any help is appreicated, thanks!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Resolution1 : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject MyButton;

    void Resolution11 () {
        Screen.SetResolution(1920, 1080, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific part are you having trouble with? Getting the button to call the function `Resolution11` or getting the screen resolution to change after calling `Screen.SetResolution`, if it is just getting the button to work take out all the extra parts of your question having to deal with screen resolution and focus your question on the problem you are actually having. Once you change your question to "How do i make a button call a function in unity" I am sure you will find turorials explaining how to do it. Example: https://youtu.be/J5ZNuM6K27E?t=505

Comment: If you want the button to execute that code you need to attach the script to an object and have the button have a click event that targets that function. https://s8.postimg.org/53bwc0gth/button.png Have you done that?